# How does one use Python to access and take data from a DB?

Tags: python, database

I am specifically referring to Aroon Swartz case, he did a program to access academical DB's such as JSTOR, IEEE, ACM, elsevier, etc. efficiently, any idea of how he did that. I mean what python libraries, or a general algorithm or an explanation of how does it work, or a reference to go deeper on that. Please, don't be shy using advanced concepts.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aroon Swartz didn't really access to JSTOR's DB. He writed a script which find URL of DB's ressources.

You can make that, with [`urllib2`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html) and [`pygoogle`](http://code.google.com/p/pygoogle/). Open URL and parse it find what you want.